# Accessing runtime java through terminal

Tags: java

Can anyone give me an idea on how to access java object to currently running application from another terminal/cmd panel.

I would like to create an application where i can access information from java running service through command prompt only like maven style "maven -version" or svn style "svn commit"...

I also want to add "start/restart/stop" into the command

Thank you

Comment: This is not a question that can be easily answered in the StackOverflow format.  You should read up on Pipes and Interprocess Communication (IPC) and then ask more specific questions.  Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea behind interprocess interaction is that you create shared accessible object. If you take a look at jetty, for example, stop command is implemented using sockets - i.e. jetty has shutdown socket and shutdown.jar which just sends some command to this socket. Another option is to use ssh server http://code.google.com/p/sshd/ or files (i.e. if you place a file inside certain directory it's treated as a command to your application. But the best way to do this is to use JMX (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html)